# How to fix Arabic unicode in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a database containing Arabic words and when I fetch the data and print it it's OK and works well and prints:

```
مشاعر‬

مودة
```

But when I loop into that database and turn it out to a list then print that list to see whats happening, I get this:

```
 ['\u202b\u202bمشاعر\u202c', '\u202b\u202bالمودة\u202c']
```

Here is the code:

```
    cors.execute("SELECT * FROM DictContents") # Selecting from database

    self.AraList = [] # empty list to put arabic words in

    for raw in cors.fetchall(): # fetching data from database

        rawAra = raw[1] # the database includes more than that so this index refer to arabic table
        print(rawAra) # here is the first print . works fine as i said .
        self.AraList.append(rawAra)
    print(self.AraList) # here is the other list printing
```

I tried more than one way to fix it before I ask but none of them worked for me.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. List output is debugging-friendly output, not end-user-friendly. Print individual values instead.

Comment: you may right but i need it to be a list as i'm passing it to a function that connect this list with a search bar that uses a QtGui.QStringListModel() module .. so it must be a list :(

Comment: Right, but then there is no problem either, because you are passing in the correct values. Don't confuse the `repr()` debugging representation with the value contained. There is no literal ``\`` or `u` or 4 hex digits; there is an actual [U+202B RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING](https://codepoints.net/U+202b) character there, but since that is hard to *see* when actually printed Python gives you the escape sequence instead. So you can easily see that that codepoint is there.

Comment: The only thing you may want to wonder about is why there are two such characters at the start of each string. You only need one, just like you only need one [U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](https://codepoints.net/U+202c) character at the end of each string.

Comment: aha so i think i got what you main here .. ? if i get it right . that's why the strings didn't  show up in the search bar . because there is tow characters  at start of the string but if its one . it will be readable ?? **Note**
i build that database table from internet parsing and  the string in html is 
<span class="Stil36">&#8235;&#8235;قلم الحبر&#8236;</span>
so here where the tow starting Chars comes from
but the question is : how to fix that :)
i think i have to rebuild it using re module instead of BeautifulSoup

Comment: No, I had no idea that you had trouble displaying the strings in a Qt GUI, you didn't state that anywhere in your question. I have no experience usig RTL Unicode text in Qt. I'm not sure why `re` would be better here over BeautifulSoup..

Comment: yes i didn't ask about that **Qt GUI** because i thought the problem is in the list itself . but after your note about the starting tow characters . i think i know now that its not the list but its from the html code . 
about re **Forget it **

Comment: finally i found a way .. like i told you . i used **Regular Expressions** to solve it and it did ..
this code 
`b = re.compile('\w+.*')
 c = b.search(a)
 if c:
     print(c.group())`
when i print the list it looks like this 
`['مشاعر\u202c - ', 'المودة\u202c']`
so **Re** Removed the first tow character but i couldn't know how to jump to the last one. thats why i wanted to use Re,don't think that BeautifulSoup has such thing . and i don't care. because it works just fine now even in the search bar that i told you about so i wanted to share this and thank you for your very useful help ..

Comment: That means that Qt doesn't support (some) [bidirectional markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode_bidi_support); you removed the initial RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found ...

```
import re
cors.execute("SELECT * FROM DictContents") 

self.AraList = [] 

for raw in cors.fetchall(): 

    rawAra = raw[1] 
    cleanit = re.compile('\w+.*')
    cleanone = cleanit .search(rawAra)
    if cleanone:
            print(cleanone.group()) # prints the clean strings : مشاعر‬ مودة 
    self.AraList.append(cleanone.group()) # adding strings to list to see how it will looks like .
print(self.AraList) # prints much better clean list than firs one 
['مشاعر\u202c - ', 'المودة\u202c']
```